# Flash Debug Player, Esc and Enter commands

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash

I have a strange or unknown behavior when i develop a project on Flash Pro. When i hit esc from keyboard, player stops the movie, when i hit enter player resumes the movie.

-What is the purpose behind this? How can i use this, is it a feature or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't use flash pro but it may be a debug feature. Did you try to publish it and test it in with a non-debug version of flash player?

Comment: i tried both debug and normal players, it did'not work. It works when debugging from Flash Pro. i will also try it on windows later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the keyboard shortcuts within Flash that stop and resume the playing of the timeline. Notice when you are testing the swf that those keyboard shortcuts show up in the Control menu at the top. It's a feature!

It won't do the same thing outside of the Flash IDE.